# How to access json_encoded php array from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a script like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".passingID", function () {
         var ids = $(this).attr('data-id');
         $("#idkl").val( ids );
         $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: "getidforeditkaryawan.php",
              data: { idkl: ids}
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#nik").val(data['nik']);
            $("#ktp").val(data['ktp']);
            $("#status").val(data['status']);
            $("#nama").val(data['nama']);
            $("#bank").val(data['bank']);
            $("#norek").val(data['norek']);
            $("#tglmsk").val(data['tgl_msk']);
            $("#tglkl").val(data['tgl_keluar']);
            $("#idp").val(data['id_perusahaan']);
            $("#tlk").val(data['tlk_individu']);
          }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
              console.log(jqXHR, textStatus);
        });
    });
```

and this is getidforeditkaryawan.php file:

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","penggajian"); 
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM karyawan_lapangan WHERE id_kl = '".$_POST['idkl']."'";
   $getdatakaryawan = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdatakaryawan);
   print_r(json_encode($data));
?>
```

but everytime i try to print the value inside the 'data' variable like this

```
console.log(data['nik']);
```

the value won't appear

the result from `print_r(json_encode($data));` is this:

```
{"id_kl":"4","nik":"13","ktp":"1231231","status":"aktif","nama":"ardia","bank":"asdasd","norek":"21313","tgl_masuk":"2019-02-14","tgl_keluar":"0000-00-00","id_perusahaan":"3123121","tlk_individu":"4124124"}
```

Comment: Use print(json_encode($data)); instead of print_r

Comment: Where is your php file located? Is it in the same folder as your js?

Comment: @pr1nc3 yes it is on the same folder

Comment: And are you sure that your query returns you the data and there are no php errors there? your console.log you have under done function returns the data you need?

Comment: yes, it returns the data i need, look at my question again i put the result from print_r(json_encode($data));

Comment: Specify the `dataType`, so that jQuery knows what you are sending back from the server is JSON. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you return a json object you can access it like:

```
$("#nik").val(data.nik);
```

Edit based on 04FS comment:

```
 $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "getidforeditkaryawan.php",
              data: { idkl: ids}
        }).
```

Missed that spot, he is right.

Comment: @kelvinsutanto: ohh i little bit late here? :)